# Jquery SmoothDivScroll not working with Flickr JSON API - loading issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, flickr

I am using this script to pull images from a Flickr photoset into my page: (it is in a js file called flickr2slideshow.js that is called in the head of my page)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var apiKey = 'I put my API key here';
var setID = 'I put the set ID here';
var userID = 'I put the user ID here';

$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + setID + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userID + '&extras=description&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(data){
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i,item){
        var slideimg = '<img src="http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '.jpg" height="200" />';
        var newthumb = $(".scrollableArea").append(slideimg);
    });

    $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        autoScroll: "always" ,
        autoScrollDirection: "endlessloopleft",
        autoScrollStep: 1,
        autoScrollInterval: 15,
        visibleHotSpots: ""
    });
});
})
```

The above script works fine and loads the images into the .scrollableArea div in my page.

The PROBLEM is that I want these photos to appear in a slideshow that uses the jQuery plugin script SmoothDivScroll. SmoothDivScroll works fine when I use it with images that are hard-coded into my page. However, the Flickr set images will not work with SmoothDivScroll when loaded into the div via my flickr4slideshow.js script). ONLY the first image in Flickr set shows up and it doesn't scroll.

My guess is that the flickr set images are still loading when the SmoothDivScroll script runs. How can I get the script to wait or start working even when the Flickr set is still being loaded into the div?

*I did test it by adding hard-coded images in to the .scrollableArea div AND using the Flickr script. When this happens, it works - first showing the hard-coded images from the html, then showing the flickr set images.

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.2 there's a new method, **changeContent**, with an option that loads content from Flickr (an RSS-feed). If you have an RSS-feed for your photoset, try loading the images by using that method. Here's an example:

```
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("changeContent", "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=34427469792@N01&format=json&jsoncallback=?", "flickrFeed", "add", "first");
```

Before you use this code you will have to initialize the plugin though. This method is not used very often (as far as I'm aware) so let me know if it works out for you and if there are any improvements that I can make in the next version.

Good luck!